# Trying to Nest a Horizontal ListView in a Vertical ListView Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I have my structure basically set up like so

```
- Column
-- Row
-- Container
-- Expanded
--- ListView (Vertical)
---- Column
----- Row
----- ListView (Horizontal)
```

Where there is a large Vertical ListView taking up most of the page with a Custom StatelessWidget, each having its own Horizontal ListView. Very similar to how Netflix has a bunch of Categories of Movies you scroll vertically through and then you can scroll through each category horizontally.

I keep getting the error

```
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: The best way to do this is by using slivers. Instead of using ListView, use SliverList and for non slivers, you can use SliverToBoxAdapter to turn them into a sliver when using them with CustomScrollview.

Comment: have you try to use `SingleChildScrollView()` ?

Comment: put some sample code if possible